# Generating map tiles with QGIS 3.6?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Similar to this rather dated [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/generating-tiles-with-qgis), is there a way to generate map tiles on QGIS 3.6? The plugins linked from that question only support QGIS 2.x. I wonder if things have changed in QGIS 3.x rendering plugins unnecessary.

Comment: @GSienko
Are you saying the QGIS layout tool can generate TMS tiles from a map? Is this documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In processing You can find gdal2tiles script. More info to find on [gdal.org](https://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html). From the description

> This utility generates a directory with small tiles and metadata, following the OSGeo Tile Map Service Specification. Simple web pages with viewers based on Google Maps, OpenLayers and Leaflet are generated as well - so anybody can comfortably explore your maps on-line and you do not need to install or configure any special software (like MapServer) and the map displays very fast in the web browser. You only need to upload the generated directory onto a web server.
>
> GDAL2Tiles also creates the necessary metadata for Google Earth (KML SuperOverlay), in case the supplied map uses EPSG:4326 projection.

[image: gdal2tiles]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if gdal2tiles can generate GeoTIFF tiles rather than PNGs?

Comment: @JohnM. There is no need. The tiling system itself is already in the layout, compatible with tms - folder and files names already specify the location. If you want to tile the map on geotiffs, use ***clip raster by extent*** or ***clip raster by mask***. just prepare only the appropriate polygon layer by which you want to divide the raster.

Comment: @JohnM. use gdal_retile for general tiling and format control